# Keyboard not responding on HP box

Tags: keyboard

I have an old old old hp media center desktop. It is a 32 bit XP system and works well but recently the keyboard has stopped typing properly. The interactive keys at the top for media functions work fine but the qwerty pad is delayed. The keys must be held for at least 2 sec to put a letter in the display and the same is true for <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd> etc.

I changed keyboards and tried other USB ports and the actual keyboard input port but the response is the same is this a setting or something I am unaware of?Perhaps a key stroke sequence? It came on suddenly and has persisted.

Comment: Does this also happen in the BIOS?